# Print multiple copies number in flowdocument

Tags: wpf, printing, flowdocument

I want to print number of copies from a flow document as the user select number of copies and print this document no of copies he selected how to do that

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what is being asked. Do you have an example or some sample code you tired, or a clearer problem specification.

Comment: I have application that Has flowdocument to view a page to print it i have a textbox to enter the nuber of copies to be printed entered by user when he click print the system should print the number of copies he selected how to do it with Flowdocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `PrintDialog` class to print your `Document` then you can set `PrintDialog.PrintTicket.CopyCount` to the value of number of copies you want

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
dialog.PrintTicket.CopyCount = NUMBEROFCOPIES;
dialog.PrintDocument();
```